# could not check the datetime field value using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am facing one issue. In my `MySQL` datetime field some value is storing like `0000-00-00` and I need to check these value. I am explaining my code below.

```
if (strtotime($data['actualdateofaudit']) == 0) {
        $data['actualdateofaudit']='';
}else{
        $data['actualdateofaudit'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data['actualdateofaudit']));
}
```

Here `actualdateofaudit` is my datetime field column name. In my case I could not check If there is any value like `0000-00-00` this. Here I need to check these type value.

Comment: _I could not check I there is any value like 0000-00-00_ Why? `strtotime('0000-00-00')` isn't zero at all.

Comment: strtotime('0000-00-00') is exactly false.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if (strtotime($data['actualdateofaudit'])) {
        $data['actualdateofaudit'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data['actualdateofaudit']));
}else{
     $data['actualdateofaudit']='';   
}
```